# Can't get fancybox to show exit button fully or fade on initial click

Tags: javascript, css, fancybox

I'm not entirely sure what code would be the best to show, but the issue that I am having does not occur in firefox/palemoon, but it does in every other major browser.

The problem can be viewed here: http://cyberbytesdesign.com/WIP2/gallery.php.  On initial page load, upon clicking one of the photos, the top right exit button is chopped off, and the shadow around the image doesn't show along with any text added to the image.

The strange thing though, is that upon changing the image, it fixes the problem, it's only an issue with the first image clicked.  I have no idea why it's doing this and I'm completely stumped.

Again, I have absolutely no idea what code I would post as I have no idea what might be encountering this error.  I'm hoping more-so that someone might have had this issue before and they know what's going on.  If you think you know any specific coding that might be the issue, I'll throw it up here to help, but I haven't an idea.

Thanks so much,

Sorry for the difficult question /:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fancybox has an inline style of `overflow: hidden`. Set it to `overflow: visible` or just remove the overflow completely.

Comment: I tried switching all overflow: hidden to overflow: visible and removing the overflow in the fancybox.min.css and it didn't fix the issue?  Do you have any idea where I must have an overflow: hidden that's doing this then if it's not in the fancybox.css?

Comment: It's an inline style, not defined in your stylesheet. You could try giving fancybox-wrap `overflow: visible !important;`.

Answer (score 1):

The `overflow` property should be updated by opening animation callback, but your page has JavaScript errors and that might stop execution of JavaScript code -

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) modernizr.custom.js:4
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function custom.js:129
```

Comment: Okay, this makes a ton of sense.. I don't know JS very well, it must be this file which I made myself.. I have no idea what's wrong with it though as everything that I put in there works: http://remodeling-buffalo.com/resource/js/custom.js

Comment: PS. how did you find those error messages? It would be helpful to be able to see that myself aswell.